# Elasticsearch many read opertions from disk

Tags: elasticsearch

We have one server (8 cpu, 18 GB ram) Elasticsearch v7.1.1, without replicas and etc.
To this server we send by fluent-bit (v1.8.15) about 5000 logs per second.

Questions is - why elastic process take many read operation from disk,  not write. (100M/s read, but at the same time just 10M/s write)

First of all i`m close kibana server, not help.

Then try change some elastic config like thread_pool.search.size - the same result

What elastic does do ? whay so many read operations ?

example output by iotop utility:

```
Total DISK READ :      77.26 M/s | Total DISK WRITE :       8.38 M/s
```

Comment: How many shards you have configured ? are you using single index or rolling index (multipul index based on date or etc) ?

Comment: index by date , 1 shard

Comment: how many index you have ? is there any dashboard visulization created using this index ?

Comment: now we have about 30 open index, we dont have any dashboard and etc. Just kibana.

Comment: i`m try stop kibana - not help. elastic procces something read from disk

Comment: is backup and snapshot is enabled ?

Comment: my understanding is that, Elasticsearch segment merging is causing this issue. Because when Elasticsearch merge the segment then first it read the data from small segment and merge it to large segment. May be you can increase number of shards and try it out.

Comment: i`m dont create any snapshots or backup.  Query ```GET /_snapshot ``` recive nothing

Comment: Ok... then whatever i have mentioned for segments merge that is correct because that is only task which is reading data and nothing else.

Comment: I'm just curious why this is a problem in the first place? Are you noticing a performance hit because of that?

Comment: sorry but i`m misstake. I`m say that we have one shard. But now run ```GET _cat/shards```
and get this image:
```logs-e-2022.10.18               0 p STARTED 108855371  31.9gb 1.1.2.3 some-node```
so we have 108855371   shards .

Comment: No it is the amount fo document you have in the shard, in `shard 0` of `index logs-e-2022.10.18` you have `108855371 ` documents, amounting to a total of `31.9gb` store on node `some-node` with ip adress `1.1.2.3`

Comment: ок, i`m try add shards to template and receive information abou how it help. Thanks for answer !

Comment: i`m add shards to index by template, from 1 to 6, and yesterday max read bytes/s , descrease from previosly 400 Mb/s to 200 Mb/s. I`m watch today and report result. Thank for help